# How to combine 3 tables with eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

How to combine 3 tables with eloquent inaravel ?

Hi Whomever help me, I need your help.

How do you combine the following three tables with eloquent in laravel?

The following table structure and figures:

Tag table structure
{tag_id: primary key, tag_name, tag_category}

Article table structure
{article_id: primary key, date_posting, content, tag_id: foreign key}

Review table structure
{review_id: primary key, date_review, reviewer_name, review_content, article_id: foreign key}

[structure table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AExPE.jpg)

Can you give me sample source code for view.blade, controller and model.

Thank you very helpful answer :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your image

*Tag are are having articles and articles are having reveiw*

Now Tag shares a [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and [many-to-one(inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationship with Article

```
use App\Article;

class Tag extends Model{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

Article model

```
use App\Tag;
use App\Review;

class Article extends Model{
    //Inverse relation for Tag and Article  
    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tag::class);
    }

   //Articles having reviews
   public function reviews()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
   }
}
```

In Review model

```
use App\Article;

class Review extends Model {
    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Article::clas);
    }

}
```

Now you can retrieve all models data using [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
App\Tag::with('articles.reviews')->get()
```